# Count all prior sections from current location in InfoPath

Tags: infopath, xpath

In the image below I would like to keep the "Sub Section X" counter from resetting when a new "Master Section" (group 1) is inserted.

[image: Nested repeating nodes]

Ideally, the form will appear as such when the counting is being performed correctly:

[image: Nested repeating nodes counting correctly]

I have found that referencing a counter outside of the repeating group (say count(//group2)) and unchecking "refresh value when formula is recalculated" proves to be unreliable.

Here is the XPath for each node:

**Group1Count:** count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1

**Group1Label:** concat("Master Section ", ../my:Group1Count)

**Group2Count:** count(../preceding-sibling::*) - 1

**Group2Label:** concat("Sub Section ", ../my:Group2Count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! I got it:

`count(../my:Group2Count/preceding::*[contains(name(), "Group2Count")]) + 1`

This filters all the preceding nodes for only those that contain the appropriate name and uses a relative path to identify the target node. This counts in the manner I specified above.

[This tutorial was quite helpful!](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/paths.html) Still picking this up as I go.